# How to add horizontal lines within a table created by Hmisc::latex()?

Tags: r, sweave

lets suppose we have a table given in R and use the function latex() from the R package Hmisc to include the table in a Sweave (or knitr) document. My question is:

*Is there a way to add horizontal lines **within** the table?*

Thanks!

Edit: I mean some option such that \cmidrule or something is added to the latex output of latex()

Greetings, 
Michael

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other(by same stack id), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `n.rgroup` to group rows; the default is to add horizontal lines.  I don't think there's a simple way to add `\cmidrule` although I haven't played with the combination of grouping rows and columns.  Also, `n.rgroup` produces a blank line after the horizontal line.  I'm not sure how to eliminate that, either.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\sisetup{group-separator={,},group-minimum-digits={3},
  output-decimal-marker={.}}
\usepackage[noae]{Sweave}
\begin{document}

<<>>=
library("Hmisc")
dat <-  matrix(c(100, 200, 300, 400,3.145,2.718,
20, 100, 10000, 10000,400,1700.42), 4)
@
<<echo=false,results=tex>>=
latex(dat,table=F,center='centering',file='',
  booktabs=T,numeric.dollar=F,colheads=c("Col A","Col B","Col C"),
      colnamesTexCmd="bfseries", col.just=c("S","S","S"),n.rgroup=c(2,2))
@

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just found a workaround for how to get rid of the extra blank lines introduced by `n.rgroup`. Below I copied the code from [Alan Munn's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129241/62746) and enclosed the `latex(...)` part as follows (as BondedDust suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17869025/4798582) to another question):

```
out <- sub("&&\\\\tabularnewline", "", capture.output(
latex(...)
))
```

Adding `writeLines(out)`then prints the table without extra blank lines.

**Minimal working example based on Alan Munn's and BondedDust's answers** (I use knitr and deleted some of the sweave packages/specifications from Alan Munn. You might need to reinsert those, and potentially also change the chunk options):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

<<echo=FALSE,results='asis', message=FALSE>>=
library("Hmisc")
dat <-  matrix(c(100, 200, 300, 400,3.145,2.718,
20, 100, 10000, 10000,400,1700.42), 4)

out <- sub("&&\\\\tabularnewline", "", capture.output( 
latex(dat,table=FALSE,center='centering',file='',
  booktabs=T,numeric.dollar=FALSE,colheads=c("Col A","Col B","Col C"),
      colnamesTexCmd="bfseries", col.just=c("S","S","S"),n.rgroup=c(2,2))
))
writeLines(out)
@

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some more elaboration: To find out what to enter instead of the questions marks in `sub("???", "", capture.output(...` I ran the following code inside R (not knitr):

```
library("Hmisc")
dat <-  matrix(c(100, 200, 300, 400,3.145,2.718,
                 20, 100, 10000, 10000,400,1700.42), 4)

capture.output( 
  latex(dat,table=FALSE,center='centering',file='',
        booktabs=T,numeric.dollar=FALSE,colheads=c("Col A","Col B","Col C"),
        colnamesTexCmd="bfseries", col.just=c("S","S","S"),n.rgroup=c(2,2))
)
```

One of the lines in the output in the console:

```
[11] "&&\\tabularnewline"
```

This is what causes an extra white line. Adding 2 more backslashes to escape each backslash results in `"&&\\\\tabularnewline"`, which is what I needed to enter instead of the question marks.